# How to replace characters of string from a list entry in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string in which I want to replace certain characters with "*". But replace() function of python doesn't replace the characters. I understand that the strings in python are immutable and I am creating a new variable to store the replaced string. But still the function doesn't provide the replaced strings.

This is the following code that I have written. I have tried the process in two ways but still don't get the desired output:

1st way:

```
a = "AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIAP"
rep = ['A','C','P']

for char in rep:
    new = a.replace(char, "*")

print(new)
```

Output:

```
AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIA*
```

2nd way:

```
a = "AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIAP"
rep = ['A','C','P']

for i in a:
    if(i in rep):
        new = a.replace(i, "*")
print(new)
```

Output:

```
AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIA*
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You assign the result of `a.replace(char, "*")` to `new`, but then on the next iteration of the `for` loop, you again replace parts of `a`, not `new`. Instead of assigning to `new`, just assign the result to `a`, replacing the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained errors in posted code.  An alternative using generator expression:

```
new = ''.join("*" if char in ['A','C','P'] else char for char in a)
print(new)
>>> '*GG*FTFG*DF*DTRF**GF*D*RTR*DF**DGFLKLI**'
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign the result of `a.replace(char, "*")` to `new`, but then on the next iteration of the `for` loop, you again replace parts of `a`, not `new`. Instead of assigning to `new`, just assign the result to `a`, replacing the original string.

```
a = "AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIAP"
rep = ['A','C','P']

for char in rep:
    a = a.replace(char, "*")

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers offered, I would suggest that regular expressions make this perhaps more straightforward, accomplishing all of the substitutions with a single function call.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIAP"
>>> rep = ['A','C','P']
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join(rep))
>>> r.sub('*', a)
'*GG*FTFG*DF*DTRF**GF*D*RTR*DF**DGFLKLI**'
```

Just in case someone decides to be clever and puts something regex significant in `rep`, you could escape those when compiling your regex.

```
r = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in rep))
```

Comment: How is `re.compile('|'.join(rep))` followed by `r.sub('*', a)` easier? Because it avoids the `for` loop? You might argue it performs better (though I'm not sure it does in this case), but it's certainly not "easier"?

Comment: @Grismar Just for fun I ran some timings (timeit). Duration for a simple loop with *replace()* = 0.34s whereas the the *re* approach (with pre-compiled pattern) = 1.83s. So, whilst the *re* approach is elegant and succinct it certainly does not perform well (not that that's got anything to do with the question)

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop is easy to understand and efficient. The crucial part of the looping approach is to re-assign the string reference to the output of *replace()*

I've taken the liberty of plagiarising two pieces of code from other contributors in order to demonstrate the performance differences (in case that's important).

```
import re
from timeit import timeit

a = "AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIAP"
rep = 'A', 'C', 'P'
p = re.compile('|'.join(rep))

def v1(s):
    for c in rep:
        s = s.replace(c, '*')
    return s

def v2(s):
    return p.sub('*', s)

def v3(s):
    return ''.join("*" if char in rep else char for char in s)

for func in v1, v2, v3:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(a)))

assert v1(a) == v2(a)
assert v1(a) == v3(a)
```

**Output:**

```
v1 0.3363962830003402
v2 1.8725565750000897
v3 3.3800653280000006
```

**Platform:**

```
macOS 13.0.1
Python 3.11.0
3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you should write `a = a.replace(i, "*")` because you are looping through `rep` and you want to do the replacement in the string `a`. Strings are immutable, and [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) gives back a copy of the string.

The variable `new` only gives you the replacement over the last iteration of rep which is a `P` char and will result in `AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIA*` because there is only a single P at the end of the string and you are never actually changing the value of rep.

If you have single characters, you can use a character class `[ACP]` with a single call to [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

a = "AGGCFTFGADFADTRFCAGFADARTRADFACDGFLKLIAP"
print(re.sub("[ACP]", "*", a))
```

Output

```
*GG*FTFG*DF*DTRF**GF*D*RTR*DF**DGFLKLI**
```